# Bootstrap column offset in react not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a row container and several div elements containing images. The first div element in the bunch has a class of `col-xs-2` as well as `offset-xs-3`. For some reason unknown to me, it will not work.

Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <div className='jumbotron' style={{'text-align': 'center'}}>

      <h1 className='header'>Welcome to Redux</h1>
      <h4 className='header_subtext'>Check out dynamic state alteration</h4>
      <br />

      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-xs-2 offset-xs-3 '>
          <img src='react.png' height='96' alt='React' onClick={this.handleVoteReact} />
        </div>
        <div className='col-xs-2'>
          <img src='vue.png' height='96' alt='React' onClick={this.handleVoteVue} />
        </div>
        <div className='col-xs-2'>
          <img src='angular.png' height='96' alt='React' onClick={this.handleVoteAngular} />
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For some reason unknown to me, it will not work.

The reason is simple:

There's NO `-xs-` in Bootstrap 4 (anymore).

Just replace `col-xs-2` with `col-2` and `offset-xs-3` with `offset-3` and it'll work.

Bootstrap 4 is "mobile first".

That's why "xs" is redundant and not needed and the reason why it was removed.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: I did not know that - I will try now

Comment: it worked! Thanks -- are the other column sizes still in bootstrap or not?

Comment: There's one more than it used to be: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options